# Is there a way to create abstract models in prisma ORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, prisma

I have few prisma models and each of these models have few common fields, for eg. audit fields like created_at, updated_at.

```
model User {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime  @updatedAt
  email      String    @unique
  username   String    @unique
  password   String?
  firstName  String?
  lastName   String?
  isActive   Boolean
  deletedAt  DateTime?
  blogs      Blog[]
  profile    Profile?
}

model Profile {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  bio        String?
  user       User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     Int      @unique
}

model Blog {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  author     User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId   Int
  title      String
  content    String

  @@unique([authorId, title])
  @@index([id, authorId])
}
```

I would like to define these all fields in one abstract base model and then extend all other models using that base model so that the repetitive code can be avoided and the risk of missing to add those fields in newer models will be lowered.

I tried to find the solution in prisma doc but I'm not able to find anything there. I can see some solutions online that are doing some hacks or using third party tools to achieve similar results but I would prefer something out of the box, if available.

For eg, In Django, we define base model and inherit other models from same. If anyone know how to achieve similar thing with prisma or if you are using some other way to manage massive number of models in production then that would be of great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: No there is such thing as abstract models or inheritance in general implemented in Prisma as of now.

However there is an open Github issue proposal which describes how interfaces could be used for that kind of abstraction.
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2506. Unfortunately there hasn't been made any real progress on the issue since 2020.

---

Thus people started to implement it by themselves.
A custom library called [ZenStack](https://zenstack.dev/) built on top of Prisma offers `abstract models`. You can define `.zmodel` model files which are compiled to the normal `prisma.schema`.

An example from the [ZenStack documentation](https://zenstack.dev/docs/reference/zmodel-language#example-3):

> ```
> abstract model Basic {
>     id String @id
>     createdAt DateTime @default(now())
>     updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
> }
>
> model User extends Basic {
>     name String 
> }
> ```
>
> The generated prisma file only contains one User model:
>
> ```
> model User {
>     id String @id
>     createdAt DateTime @default(now())
>     updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
>     name String @id
> }
> ```

Comment: Since there is noting officially supported by Prisma, using zenstack looks good for now.

Answer (score 0):

Prisma ORM does not have the concept of "abstract models" in the same way Django ORM does. In Django, an abstract model serves as a base class for other models but does not produce a database table of its own. Instead, its fields are added to the child models that inherit from it.

In Prisma, you can't define a model that is only used for inheritance purposes. However, there are certain approaches you can take to emulate abstract-like behavior:

**Using Generators or Scripts:**

You could set up a generator or a script to produce the final schema.prisma file by combining shared fields and model-specific fields. This is a more involved setup but can help maintain DRYness if you have a lot of shared fields.

**Model Relations instead of Inheritance:**

Consider if a relation between models might serve better than inheritance. For instance, if there's a shared set of attributes across multiple models, those attributes could be refactored into their own model, and a relation could be established.

```
model Profile {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String
  email   String @unique
  user    User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId  Int?
  admin   Admin? @relation(fields: [adminId], references: [id])
  adminId Int?
}

model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  profile Profile  @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id])
  profileId Int
  // ... other specific fields ...
}

model Admin {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  profile Profile  @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id])
  profileId Int
  // ... other specific fields ...
}
```

In this example, the Profile model holds fields common to both User and Admin.

Comment: I can see few issues with this approach. 1. Creating separate relation for the common fields that always be on almost all models will make the heavy use of joins which is un-necessary. 2. It will make the referencing table exponentially large because we are now storing common fields from all models, which will require separate handling. 3. As a design perspective, it makes sense to have those common fields on the record row itself because it's something that will be used almost everytime for some checks. So, having separate table seems to be a hack.